# Close telerik radwindow from server side in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I created loading window with telerik radwindow but I am not able close it from server side in C#.

Could anyone help me?

```
protected void bt_next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string script = "function f(){ window.radopen(\"\", \"windows_loading\");Sys.Application.remove_load(f); }Sys.Application.add_load(f);";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "key", script, true);

    //here i connect with database and insert all info to database and then i want close the radwindow.

}
```

Comment: Please post your current code.

Comment: If it's a client-side component then server-side code can't interact with it after the page has been sent to the browser.  What are you trying to do, what have you tried, and how is it failing?

Comment: "Could anyone help me?" Not without any code to look at...

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the desired functionality like this,
Server Side (i.e button click etc):

```
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "CloseRadWindow();", true);
```

Then on Client Side use these Jquery Methods:

```
function CloseRadWindow() {
    //get a reference to the current RadWindow
    var wndow = GetRadWindow();
    wndow .Close();
}

function GetRadWindow() {
    var oWindow = null;
    if (window.radWindow) oWindow = window.radWindow;
    else if (window.frameElement.radWindow) oWindow = window.frameElement.radWindow;
    return oWindow;
}
```

Comment: There are several scenarios and two ways this reference may be obtained, which are explained here http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/window/client-side-programming/overview

Answer (score 0):

this worked fro me:

aspx:

```
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

aspx script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    function GetRadWindow() {
        var oWindow = null;
        if (window.radWindow)
            oWindow = window.radWindow;
        else if (window.frameElement && window.frameElement.radWindow)
            oWindow = window.frameElement.radWindow;
        return oWindow;
    }


    function CloseModal() {
        GetRadWindow().close();

    }



</script>
```

aspx.cs:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript", "setTimeout(function(){ CloseModal(); },250);", true);
```